# Significance levels vs Information criterion

Tags: statistical-significance, model-selection, aic, bic

Modelling financial time series data.

My mean equation was an AR(1) process. Planning to forecast the data in-sample and I have a TGARCH with IC indicating it is a better model, but the p-value for the AR(1) is .0566, whereas an EGARCH model has a significant (5%) AR(1) value but its IC indicate the TGARCH is superior.

Which should I use? (Worth mentioning the aim is to have the best fit model)

Comment: The use of statistical significance vs. information criteria for model selection has been discussed in multiple previous posts. You could benefit from checking them out.

Comment: Any links? Have looked briefly but unable to find anything concrete. Would really appreciate anything.